# How to replace DB2 WEEK function to Oracle function?

Tags: oracle, db2

I am trying to replace DB2 with Oracle DB.

In DB2, there is a WEEK function, which returns the number of weeks of the year.
For example:

```sql
SELECT week('2021-01-04') FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Then I get the return of 2 (as DB2 WEEK function regards Sunday as the first day of the week.)

However, in Oracle, if I make a similar query, then I get a different value.

```sql
SELECT to_char(to_date('2021-01-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'WW') FROM dual;
```

I get the value of 1 (not 2 as Oracle regards January 1st as the first day of the week.)

Is there any other turnaround or different function to replace DB2 WEEK function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count the number of weeks where the first day of the week is Sunday then:

```sql
SELECT FLOOR(
         (DATE '2021-01-04' - NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( DATE '2021-01-04', 'YY' ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'SUNDAY'))
         / 7
       ) + 1
       AS week
FROM   your_input;
```

Which outputs `2`.

If you run it with multiple input days:

```sql
WITH your_input ( value ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2021-01-01' + LEVEL - 1
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 32
)
SELECT value,
       FLOOR(
         (value - NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( value, 'YY' ) - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'SUNDAY'))
         / 7
       ) + 1
       AS week
FROM   your_input;
```

Then you get the output (with the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` as `YYYY-MM-DD (DY)`):

> | VALUE | WEEK |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2021-01-01 (FRI) | 1 |
> | 2021-01-02 (SAT) | 1 |
> | 2021-01-03 (SUN) | 2 |
> | 2021-01-04 (MON) | 2 |
> | 2021-01-05 (TUE) | 2 |
> | 2021-01-06 (WED) | 2 |
> | 2021-01-07 (THU) | 2 |
> | 2021-01-08 (FRI) | 2 |
> | 2021-01-09 (SAT) | 2 |
> | 2021-01-10 (SUN) | 3 |
> | 2021-01-11 (MON) | 3 |
> | 2021-01-12 (TUE) | 3 |
> | 2021-01-13 (WED) | 3 |
> | 2021-01-14 (THU) | 3 |
> | 2021-01-15 (FRI) | 3 |
> | 2021-01-16 (SAT) | 3 |
> | 2021-01-17 (SUN) | 4 |
> | 2021-01-18 (MON) | 4 |
> | 2021-01-19 (TUE) | 4 |
> | 2021-01-20 (WED) | 4 |
> | 2021-01-21 (THU) | 4 |
> | 2021-01-22 (FRI) | 4 |
> | 2021-01-23 (SAT) | 4 |
> | 2021-01-24 (SUN) | 5 |
> | 2021-01-25 (MON) | 5 |
> | 2021-01-26 (TUE) | 5 |
> | 2021-01-27 (WED) | 5 |
> | 2021-01-28 (THU) | 5 |
> | 2021-01-29 (FRI) | 5 |
> | 2021-01-30 (SAT) | 5 |
> | 2021-01-31 (SUN) | 6 |
> | 2021-02-01 (MON) | 6 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b657e34ac6f59ed7c6326b29ac8264fe)*

Answer (score 2):

Oracle offers two Week of Year Number functions. As you have discovered, `to_char(dt, 'WW')` gives a number in which the week starts on 1st of January and increments every seven days. There is also `to_char(dt, 'IW')` giving the ISO week number, which runs Monday to Sunday; in this case the 1st of January is Week 53 and 2021-01-04 is the first day of week 1 of 2021.

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ec363475e2e8ba5ab96c6b2f97b94fdf)

There is no function in Oracle which increments the week number on the basis of the day of the week number. You could write your own PL/SQL function to do this.

---

Incidentally, the first day of the week in Oracle is determined by our NLS parameters. If we run with (say) American settings Sunday is day 1; if we run with British settings then Monday is day 1.